# draw binary tree with php

Tags: php, jquery, graph, gd, binary-tree

I'm looking for a good library / API to draw a binary tree using PHP.
I've tried using Image_GraphViz, but it doesn't seem to work. I've also looked at phpsyntaxtree, but its not documented.

Alternatively, I'm also looking for a jQuery plugin that does this. (just not [this one](http://frank-mich.com/jQuery/) because it has **no** documentation).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to go with js, because vector graphs are nicer and you can add interactivity anytime.

Try raphael, a good (and perfectly documented) js graph library

[homepage](http://raphaeljs.com/) | [tree graph demo](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html)

Answer (score 2):

I still believe [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is what you need. If you had a problem in using it, just post a question about the problem. It will be better than finding an alternative tool.